# Applying lambda functions to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
   id   values
1  34   ['de, fa qe', 'ml, fr']
2  45   ['op er, qe', 'm, qn', 'asd, qwe, zxc']
```

I want to end with:

```
   id   values
1  34   ['de, fa qe, ml, fr']
2  45   ['op er, qe, m, qn, asd, qwe, zxc']
```

I'm thinking about using this function

```
merger=lambda x, y:x+y
```

But I can't figure out how to apply it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) using the [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) accessor.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [34, 45],
                   'values': [['de, fa qe', 'ml, fr'], 
                              ['op er, qe', 'm, qn', 'asd, qwe, zxc']]})

>>> df['values'].str.join(', ')
0                  de, fa qe, ml, fr
1    op er, qe, m, qn, asd, qwe, zxc
Name: values, dtype: object

>>> df['values'].str.join(', ').iat[-1]
'op er, qe, m, qn, asd, qwe, zxc'
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **values** as a column name, it conflicts with the DataFrame attribute **values**.

If you have the DataFrame:

```
   id   column1
1  34   ['de, fa qe', 'ml, fr']
2  45   ['op er, qe', 'm, qn', 'asd, qwe, zxc']
```

it's just using the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method on the Series you want. For instance:

```
merger=lambda x: [''.join(s) for s in x]
df.column1 = df['column1'].apply(merger)
```

Comment: what is `y` in your lambda function? ;)

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @MaxU! Hadn't looked at the lambda function carefully.